# Error en, juego de zombies Java

Tags: java

Tengo un programa grande con 5 clases, en las que cada vez que ejecuto me sale este error en `NetBeans`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las diferentes clases:

-CLASE 1, **Batoilkingdead**:

```
public static final int NUMERO_DE_VIDAS = 3;
private static final boolean GAME_OVER = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BatoilkingDead.inicio();
}

public static void inicio() {
//Creacion de las Casillas del JUEGO
    int[][] ResultadoCasillas =           Casillas.creaCasillasEscenarioJuego();
    int[] posicionSuperviviente = Superviviente.creaPosicionSuperviviente(ResultadoCasillas);
    int[][] posicionesDelZombie = Zombies.creaPosicionZombie(ResultadoCasillas);

    do {
        //Muestra el juego llamando a las diferentes clases:
        Partidas.imprimirCasillas(ResultadoCasillas, posicionesDelZombie, posicionSuperviviente);

        String moverSupervivientePorLasCasillas = Partidas.comprobarOrden(Partidas.pedirOrden());
        Superviviente.moverSuperviviente(posicionSuperviviente, posicionesDelZombie, ResultadoCasillas, moverSupervivientePorLasCasillas);

        Zombies.MovimientoZombieAleatorio(ResultadoCasillas, posicionesDelZombie, posicionSuperviviente);
    } while (!GAME_OVER);
  }
}
```

CLASE 2, **Casillas**

```
public static final int TIPO_LIMITE = 2;
public static final int TIPO_ITEM = 3;

public static int[][] creaCasillasEscenarioJuego() {
    int lmte = TIPO_LIMITE;
    int item = TIPO_ITEM;
    int nada = TIPO_VACIA;

    int[][] casillas = new int[][]{
        //0
        {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte},
        {lmte, item, item, item, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, item, lmte},
        {lmte, item, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, item, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte},
        {lmte, item, item, item, item, item, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, lmte},
        {lmte, item, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte},
        {lmte, item, nada, nada, nada, lmte, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, lmte, item, lmte},
        {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte},
        {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, lmte, item, lmte},
        {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, item, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, item, item, lmte},
        {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, lmte, item, lmte},
        {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte},
        {lmte, item, item, item, item, lmte, item, item, item, lmte, item, item, item, lmte, item, lmte},
        {lmte, item, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte},
        {lmte, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, lmte},
        {lmte, item, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte},
        {lmte, item, item, item, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, lmte, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, lmte},
        {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte}
    };
    return casillas;

}

public static boolean noEsLimite(int[][] casillas, int x, int y) {
    return casillas[x][y] != TIPO_LIMITE;
}

public static boolean hayItem(int[][] casillas, int x, int y) {
    return casillas[x][y] == TIPO_ITEM;

}

public static void vaciarCasilla(int[][] casillas, int x, int y) {
    casillas[x][y] = TIPO_VACIA; //asigna el valor de la casilla vacia

}

public static boolean comprobarVacia(int[][] casillas, int x, int y) {
    return casillas[x][y] == TIPO_VACIA;
}

public static String representacionGrafica(int[][] casillas, int x, int y) {
    String representacion = "";

    switch (casillas[x][y]) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println(" ");
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println(" "); //He cambiado el . por este simbolo, ya que no se ve bien
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("\" \" ");

        default:
            System.out.println("No existe este número");
            break;
    }
    return representacion;

}

//Metodo que utilizo para comprobar las columnas vacias
public static boolean comprobarColumnasVacias(int[][] casillas) {
    boolean columnas = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < casillas.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < casillas[0].length; j++) {
            if (casillas[i][j] == Casillas.TIPO_VACIA) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return columnas;
}

  //Metodo que utilizo para comprobar la posicion correcta de cada    fila y cada columna
public static boolean esUnaposicionCorrecta(int[]    posicionSeTieneComprobar, int[][] posicionesEnLasQueHayQueComprobar, int[] movimiento, int[][] casillas) {
    int posicionFila = posicionSeTieneComprobar[0] + movimiento[0];
    int posicionColumna = posicionSeTieneComprobar[1] + movimiento[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < posicionSeTieneComprobar.length; i++) {
        if (!(posicionFila == posicionesEnLasQueHayQueComprobar[i][0] && posicionColumna == posicionesEnLasQueHayQueComprobar[i][1])) {
            if (Casillas.noEsLimite(casillas, posicionFila, posicionColumna)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

CLASE 3, **Partidas**

```
public static final String MOVIMIENTO_ARRIBA = "W";
public static final String MOVIMIENTO_ABAJO = "S";
public static final String MOVIMIENTO_IZQUIERDA = "A";
public static final String MOVIMIENTO_DERECHA = "H";
public static final String EXIT = "E";

public static final int PUNTOS_JUEGO = 10;

public static void imprimirCasillas(int[][] casillas, int[][] posicionZombie, int[] posicionSuperviviente) {
    for (int i = 0; i < casillas.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("");
        for (int j = 0; j < casillas[0].length; j++) {
            int[] posicionCasillas = {i, j}; // array que he creado para almacenar las posiciones de las casillas
            if (compararPosicionZombies(posicionCasillas, posicionZombie)) {
                System.out.print(" Z ");
            } else if (compararPosicionSuperviviente(posicionCasillas, posicionSuperviviente)) {
                System.out.print(" S ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(Casillas.representacionGrafica(casillas, i, j));
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.print("");

    System.out.println("Te quedan un total de: " + BatoilkingDead.NUMERO_DE_VIDAS + " vidas.");

}

public static String pedirOrden() {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("¿Qué quieres hacer ahora?");
    String direccion = teclado.nextLine();
    return direccion;
}

public static String comprobarOrden(String orden) {
    while (true) {

        if (orden.length() == 1) {
            if ((orden.charAt(0) >= 70 && orden.charAt(0) <= 80) || (orden.charAt(0) >= 96 && orden.charAt(0) <= 122)) {
                switch (orden) {
                    case MOVIMIENTO_ARRIBA:
                        return "arriba";
                    case MOVIMIENTO_ABAJO:
                        return "abajo";
                    case MOVIMIENTO_IZQUIERDA:
                        return "izquierda";
                    case MOVIMIENTO_DERECHA:
                        return "derecha";
                    case EXIT:
                        System.exit(0);
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Orden no encontrada. POR FAVOR. Vuelve a intentarlo:");
                        orden = pedirOrden();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("POR FAVOR. Introduce una direccion valida.");
        orden = pedirOrden();
    }
}

public static boolean compararPosicionZombies(int[] posicion, int[][] posicionesZombie) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= posicionesZombie[0].length; i++) {
        if (posicion[0] == posicionesZombie[i][0] && posicion[1] == posicionesZombie[i][1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean compararPosicionSuperviviente(int[] posicion, int[] posicionSuperviviente) {
    return posicion[0] == posicionSuperviviente[0] && posicion[1] == posicionSuperviviente[1];
  }

}
```

CLASE 4, **Supervivientes**

```
public static Random random = new Random(); //Creo un objeto para los personajes aleatorios

public static final String representacionSuperviviente = "S";

public static int[] creaPosicionSuperviviente(int[][] casillas) {

    //metodo que he hecho para comprobar si la posicion esta vacia y generar un número aleatorio.
    int x;
    int y;
    int[] posicionSuperviviente = new int[2];
    if (Casillas.comprobarColumnasVacias(casillas)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < posicionSuperviviente.length; i++) {

            do {
                x = random.nextInt(casillas[0].length - 1);
                y = random.nextInt(casillas.length - 1);

            } while (!Casillas.comprobarVacia(casillas, x, y));

            posicionSuperviviente[0] = x;
            posicionSuperviviente[1] = y;
        }

    }
    return posicionSuperviviente;
}

//ACTUALIZAR LA POSICION DEL SUPERVIVIENTE
public static void moverSuperviviente(int[] posicionSuperviviente, int[][] posicionesZombies, int[][] casillas, String movimiento) {

    int x = posicionSuperviviente[0], y = posicionSuperviviente[1]; //posicion del personaje con las coordenadas x y del array

    switch (movimiento) { //menu switch donde hago el movimiento del personaje
        case "arriba":
            if (comprobarPosicionSuperviviente(x, y + 1, casillas)) {
                y++;
            }
            break;
        case "abajo":
            if (comprobarPosicionSuperviviente(x, y - 1, casillas)) {
                y--;
            }
            break;
        case "derecha":
            if (comprobarPosicionSuperviviente(x + 1, y, casillas)) {
                x++;
            }
            break;
        case "izquierda":
            if (comprobarPosicionSuperviviente(x - 1, y, casillas)) {
                x--;
            }
            break;
    }
    posicionSuperviviente[0] = x; //posicion final del superviviente
    posicionSuperviviente[1] = y;
}
//metodo que comprueba la posicion del superviviente

public static boolean comprobarPosicionSuperviviente(int x, int y, int[][] casillas) {

    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || y > casillas.length || x > casillas[0].length) {
        return false;
    }

    return casillas[y][x] != 0;
  }
}
```

CLASE 5, **Zombies**:

```
public static Random random = new Random();
public static final String ZOMBIE = "Z";
public static final int Zombies = 3;

public static int[][] creaPosicionZombie(int[][] casillas) {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    /**
     * He creado una array (posicionDelZombie) para comprobar las casillas
     * vacias, si hay una casilla vacia genera números aleatorios
     */

    int[][] posicionDelZombie = new int[Zombies][2];

    if (Casillas.comprobarColumnasVacias(casillas)) {

        for (int i = 0; i < posicionDelZombie.length; i++) {

            do {

                x = random.nextInt(casillas[0].length);
                y = random.nextInt(casillas.length);

            } while (!Casillas.comprobarVacia(casillas, x, y));

            if (i != 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Zombies; j++) {
                    if (posicionDelZombie[i][0] != posicionDelZombie[i - 1][0] && posicionDelZombie[i][1] != posicionDelZombie[i - 1][1]) {
                        posicionDelZombie[i][0] = x;
                        posicionDelZombie[i][1] = y;
                    } else {
                        i--;

                    }
                }
            } else {
                posicionDelZombie[i][0] = x;
                posicionDelZombie[i][1] = y;
            }
        }
    }

    return posicionDelZombie;
}

//En este metodo, se decide el metodo del zombie aleatoriamente
public static void MovimientoZombieAleatorio(int[][] casillas, int[][] pZombie, int[] posicionSuperviviente) {

    int movimiento;
    boolean esValido = false;
    int numeroDeIntentos = 0;
    int casillasDondePasaElZombie = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < pZombie.length; i++) {
        int cFilaZombie = pZombie[i][0];
        int cColumnaZombie = pZombie[i][1];
        int[] posicionZombie = {cFilaZombie, cColumnaZombie};
        //Direcciones
        int[] movimientoArriba = {-casillasDondePasaElZombie, 0};
        int[] movimientoAbajo = {casillasDondePasaElZombie, 0};
        int[] movimientoIzquierda = {0, -casillasDondePasaElZombie};
        int[] movimientoDerecha = {0, casillasDondePasaElZombie};
        do {

            //genero 3 numero aleatorios y despues un menu segun el numero que haya salido(arriba,abajo,derecha,izquierda)
            movimiento = random.nextInt(3);

            switch (movimiento) {
                case 0:
                    if (Casillas.esUnaposicionCorrecta(posicionZombie, pZombie, movimientoArriba, casillas)) {
                        cFilaZombie -= casillasDondePasaElZombie;
                        esValido = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (Casillas.esUnaposicionCorrecta(posicionZombie, pZombie, movimientoAbajo, casillas)) {
                        cFilaZombie += casillasDondePasaElZombie;
                        esValido = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (Casillas.esUnaposicionCorrecta(posicionZombie, pZombie, movimientoIzquierda, casillas)) {
                        cFilaZombie -= casillasDondePasaElZombie;
                        esValido = true;
                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (Casillas.esUnaposicionCorrecta(posicionZombie, pZombie, movimientoDerecha, casillas)) {
                        cFilaZombie += casillasDondePasaElZombie;
                        esValido = true;
                    }

                    numeroDeIntentos++;

            }
        } while (esValido == false && numeroDeIntentos < 3);

        /**
         * Si no encuentra una posicion aleatoriamente se busca una entre
         * todas las direcciones posibles, igual que el anterior metodo, lo
         * he utilizado para buscar entre las posiciones libres.
         *
         */
        if (esValido == false) {
            boolean caminoElegido = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                switch (j) {

                    case 0:     //arriba
                        if (Casillas.esUnaposicionCorrecta(posicionZombie, pZombie, movimientoArriba, casillas)) {
                            cFilaZombie -= casillasDondePasaElZombie;
                            caminoElegido = true;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 1:     //abajo
                        if (Casillas.esUnaposicionCorrecta(posicionZombie, pZombie, movimientoAbajo, casillas)) {
                            cFilaZombie += casillasDondePasaElZombie;
                            caminoElegido = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:     //izquierda
                        if (Casillas.esUnaposicionCorrecta(posicionZombie, pZombie, movimientoIzquierda, casillas)) {
                            cColumnaZombie -= casillasDondePasaElZombie;
                            caminoElegido = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:     //derecha
                        if (Casillas.esUnaposicionCorrecta(posicionZombie, pZombie, movimientoDerecha, casillas)) {
                            cColumnaZombie += casillasDondePasaElZombie;
                            caminoElegido = true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                if (caminoElegido == true) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        pZombie[i][0] = cFilaZombie;
        pZombie[i][1] = cColumnaZombie;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Es correcto que en la siguiente linea, tengas un comparador y no un asignador de valor? public static boolean comprobarVacia(int[][] casillas, int x, int y) { return casillas[x][y] == TIPO_VACIA;
} donde dices return casillas[x][y] == TIPO_VACIA; no debiera ser return casillas[x][y] = TIPO_VACIA; o algo por el estilo, ya que no me queda muy claro el hecho de en la casilla a b, ubicada en x y, asignale tipo_vacia, el cual es solo un int.

Comment: @MauricioRoss es correcto lo que hace bpico, pues ese método devuelve un `boolean` que es lo que entrega ese comparador. Lo que tú dices no compilaría porque no estaría devolviendo un `boolean`.

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta que debe resolver tu problema. No obstante deberías de aprovechar las herramientas que te da la POO para reutilizar código para objetos que comparten comportamientos. Superviviente y Zombie son objetos que se mueven y que por tanto pueden abstraerse esas funcionalidades a una clase `EnteMovible` o una interfaz `Movible` que te haga tener más ordenado el código y con los atributos de cada objeto protegidos antes que usar métodos estáticos por todos lados. Tal cual lo tienes es poco reutilizable.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Hola, voy a comprobar la respuesta anterior. Perdona que no lo haya hecho con POO. En clase nos exige que sea así, mas adelante ya entraremos en lo que me has comentado. Muchas gracias por ayudarme

Comment: ¿Al final te sirvió la respuesta o no? Ya tengo curiosidad...

Comment: No, ahora lo estoy implementando con POO @Awes0meM4n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estas cambiando las coordenadas `x` por `y`. Lo normal es que te refieras a las `x` como el número de arreglos `y` de n elementos. En tu caso la `x` máxima es 16 y la `y` máxima es 15.

Al hacer:

```
x = random.nextInt(casillas[0].length);
y = random.nextInt(casillas.length);
```

y no ser una matriz cuadrada se te desborda ya que después para comprobar que está vacía lo miras al revés:

```
casillas[x][y] == TIPO_VACIA;//primero filas y luego columnas
```

Cambia esas líneas poniéndolas al revés:

```
x = random.nextInt(casillas.length);
y = random.nextInt(casillas[0].length);
```

o comprobar pasándole al método `Casillas.comprobarVacia(casillas, y, x)` y así las comprobará cambiadas.

Si no te sale ese error ya tienes tu respuesta. Eso no quita que según hayas diseñado los resultados que dibujes te salgan traspuestos porque no he visto tu código para pintarlos.